# Is there a way to disable ReSharper for a specific file?

Tags: resharper

I want to tell ReSharper to ignore a few files in my project. Some of them are just too large (they contain canned test data). Some of them are just confusing it (with a mishmash of Silverlight and .NET code).

Is there a way to do this by putting a comment at the top of the file?

However it's done, it needs to be persistent (i.e. can be checked in), and per-file.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860743/8446), but it doesn't appear to be persisted.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In order to skip inspections in some files or folders go to **ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings** -> **Edit Items to Skip** button. Or if your code is generated add it to appropriate list in **ReSharper | Options | Generate Code** section. You can read more about how it works [here](http://hadihariri.com/2011/06/27/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/).

Comment: Are those persistent? Which files (if any) do I need to check in? Will they work if another team member checks them out?

Comment: If you want to share it with your team members, save changed settings to `solution '...' team-shared` layer. And add `YourSolution.sln.DotSettings` to VCS. Or to do it only for yourself - save to `solution '...' personal` layer.

Answer (score 64):

This may be a feature in a more recent version than the one available when the question was originally asked.

It is possible to suppress code inspection for a specific block (or file) by using the comments:

```
// ReSharper disable All
```

and

```
// ReSharper restore All
```

See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Quick_Start.html#analyzing-code).

Comment: Note that seems to be case sensitive, at least in R# 8.1. I initially added "disable all" and "restore all", since this is similar to standard directives, but that did not work.

Comment: keep in mind, that this only works in the UI, not for code cleanup operations.

Comment: I prefer this answer over the others because it is team shared.

Comment: Perfect!. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 62):

You can apply this to individual files via a shortcut key.

With the file open try both of these (the actual shortcut depends upon your environment).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

You will see that it toggles the processing of this specific file.

The name of this shortcut in the Keyboard dialog is `ReSharper_EnableDaemon`.

Comment: For toggling Code Inspection back on you have to use the same shortcut keys: CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + 8