# Resharper 9.2 does not recognize symbols in a .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, resharper

I've created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` project via the File/New Project mechanism in VS2015.  I open up _Layout.cshtml and I see red all over the place.

It seems Resharper does not recognize things like ViewData, RenderSection, Model, etc..

Is there anyway to fix this? 
P.S.  I should mention that I tried all the usual suspects (clearing cache, suspend/restart Resharper, etc...)

[image]

P.P.S For other folks with this problem, I just disabled Resharper for .cshtml extension per the winning answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725692/is-there-a-way-to-disable-resharper-for-a-specific-file) question.

Comment: What makes you think this is R# and not just VS2015?

Comment: @DavidG Because if I disable Resharper, everything is recognized and I get intellisense.

Comment: You are probably experiencing issues since resharper 9.2 is over 1.5 years old and .NET core is a rapidly changing framework at the moment.  I have a sneaky feeling that R# is simply out of date.  https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-