# How can I tell ReSharper that I'm using a wrapper for Debug.Assert to avoid null ref warnings?

Tags: c#, resharper

So I used to have `Debug.Assert` all around my code but now I have created a `DebugHelper.Assert` which in itself has some logging and a `Debug.Assert` but now I'm getting 1 million of warnings that something can be null.

Can I tell ReSharper that doing `DebugHelper.Assert` is the same as `Debug.Assert` and thus get rid of the warnings?

EDIT:
I would really like (also maybe have to) avoid adding another dependency to the project just for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854701/disable-all-resharper-warnings-with-a-comment

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal That simply disables all warnings, not what's being asked here

Comment: @Rob: I know, but something to think on these lines. Instead of giving a pre baked answer to OP, I directed him to think on these line, informing that this 'kind' of functionalities do exist in Resharper. I have link to exact answer which he wants to find. but why give a Man a Fish....

Answer (score 3):

You want to add an attribute to the `DebugHelper.Assert` method. You can reference the JetBrains.Annotations package in your project, and add a Contract assertion, something like:

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("condition:false => halt")]
public void Assert(bool condition)
{
  // ...
}
```

This tells ReSharper that if the `condition` parameter is false, the method will halt. This is how ReSharper annotates the standard `Debug.Assert` method (albeit via "external" annotations in an xml file, rather than inline in the code).

You can also mark the JetBrains.Annotations package as a development time dependency - the attributes are conditional, and not compiled into the resulting binary by default. More details in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/).

Comment: This is a nice solution, however I'm not sold on creating a dependency on Jetbrains' library (even a development dependency). Do you know if it's possible to do the same with resharper configuration files - I suppose, similar to how they annotate `Debug.Assert`?

Comment: +1 to @Rob . I'm really not liking this idea of adding a dependency and I'm not sure whether I will be allowed to even use it as a dev dependency because of my companies policies where I may need additional approval. I would really like to avoid adding this

Comment: Could this somehow be used https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html ?
EDIT: Looks to me like not. It seems these can't be applied back to the same project

Comment: I can't accept this as an answer. I need something that doesn't add an extra dependency to my solution

Comment: If you add a nuget reference, it doesn't get compiled into the project, as all of the attributes are conditional. This means that although you have a reference, you don't need to distribute the library. Alternatively, and also documented in the blog post, you can add the source for the annotations to your project. These will be `internal` classes, so they don't become part of your public API, and because they're conditional, they don't even get compiled into the resulting binary.